# How to change lightworks project frame rate?

Tags: video, editing

I created a project with 60fps.
Imported videos which are at 25fps (using eyeframe converter).
Did all my editing, took me forever and exported the project.
Again used eyeframe converter to get .mp4.

Here was the problem, the video was playing at higher rate (meaning it was playing at double or more faster speed),
but the audio was playing at normal rate.

Now I am wondering is it possible to change the project fps or
copy the edit into a new project which is at 25fps?

Please help me.

Comment: So, you accidentally created it at 60fps?

Comment: Yes, I din't notice the fps settings. Now I am unable to change the settings.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used LightWorks recently or extensively, and I am not sure how the whole EyeFrame converter works, but if you want to change your output frame-rate, I think [this](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=20&id=1064&Itemid=81) link will help.

In it (the link), user HammerHead says:

> You choose the *project-rate* when you first create your project from the projects browser (the window that you see when you first run up the app). This governs the frame-rate that all your edits are created at in that project.
>
> Once you enter that project/room you can then change the *output* rate in that project using the setting you describe on the project-card. So if you're in a 25fps project, the available playback rates will be 25 & 50.
>
> **To make a 30fps project, go back to the projects-browser (by clicking the arrow icon in the lower right corner), and fill in the details at the top.**

I'm pretty sure that the sentence I took the liberty of making bold, is the answer. Also, the user was asking for a 30fps video but it should work for 25fps. Read the whole link for more details.

I don't think this is what you are looking for, but [here](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=23&id=11273&Itemid=81) is another link, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, finally I can continue with  my project from I left off :)

Comment: Glad to help @KirkHammett! If this answered your question, then make sure to accept this answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I couldn't change my fps setting like how it is described.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I haven't used LightWorks in along time, but just installed it and found that I couldn't do it either. If you aren't very far in a project, I would just recommend that you restart... Not that that would be optimal for large projects. There _should_ be some way to do what you need. I'll try to look into it some more.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Lightworks (11.5.1) you can change the Output framerate (and other formats) from the Project menu in the top right corner:

[image: Change output format]

1. Click on the menu arrow by "Project *Name*"
2. Select "Video"
3. Click on the menu arrow for "Output format" and choose a different target FPS.